# How to show progress in the System Tray

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, progress, system-tray

I am trying to display progress in the system tray. I use this:

```
    ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = pi;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

The problem I have is changing the Progress Indicator's maximum value. The default seems to be one, but I see no way of changing this. How would you do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the ProgressIndicator takes is a `double` value between `0` and `1`.

If you want to put any other numbers into it (say `0` to `100`) what you have to do is `normalise` the values, which will bring them into the range `0-1`.

so for example you would do:

```
double progress = 0.0;
double max = 100.0;

progress = 0.0/max;  // = 0.0
pi.Value = progress;

progress = 50.0/max; // = 0.5
pi.Value = progress;

progress = 100.0/max; // = 1.0
pi.Value = progress;
```

and you would input the values between `0 and 1`.

[Here is a good little post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/06/04/system-tray-progress-indicator.aspx) about this feature.